# Why can't I discard a message using rsyslog `stop`?

Tags: rsyslog

Here is my rsyslog filter:

```
if $syslogtag == 'mytag:' then {
*.!warning stop
}
```

I think this should discard all messages with the tag of 'mytag' where the priority is `warning` or less.  So I tried a `debug`, `warning` and `error` log but **all three** messages appear on `/var/log/messages`.  I've used a similar tag filter elsewhere successfully and `*.* stop` seems to discard messages with all priorities so what and I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have stumbled across the answer; the filter needs to be this:

```
if $syslogtag == 'mytag:' then {
*.debug;*.!warning stop
}
```

This says 'priority debug or greater' AND 'priority warning or less' has action 'stop' applied.  Seems odd that I have to effectively 'select all then filter'; I would have expected the starting point for a negative filter to be 'everything' but apparently not!

The man page for syslog.conf (sic) contains an example; look for the example containing

```
kern.info;kern.!err          /var/adm/kernel-info
```